# Make paid app free for specific user

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible for me as an developer/owner of my paid app (released on the Google Play market) to unlock its full version for specific user?

Comment: Why not just send him/her your APK?

Comment: 1. I do not trust him, he can uppload this app somewhere for everyone. 2. If I update an app he will not get na update.

Comment: Is this really related to game development?

Comment: Would go much better on Android.SE (sorry, I forgot to finish my message - I blame the lack of sleep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been discussed on the [Google forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-discuss/ey9eE1w1zes). Basically, there isn't a really easy option, but the options discussed in the thread are:

1. Buy gift cards and give the gift card codes to user to purchase your app. Issues: You'll lose money on this transaction and the user is not required to buy your app, potentially losing you even more.
2. Create a free version of the app that can accept an unlock code to be upgraded to the full version. Issues: If you don't already have something like this in place, it'll be a good deal of work to get implemented. The unlock codes would be single/limited use, so that would require a server for validation. That adds additional cost to this scenario.

The quickest and easiest of the two is to use the gift cards. But the most suitable for long term is the unlock codes. An additional benefit of the unlock codes is having the infrastructure in place for any future apps you develop. (Or maybe selling the library to other developers).

Comment: Also, nothing stops the user from publishing the unlock code.

Comment: @JariKomppa, unlocking might involve server side validation, but that is even more work.

Comment: if the server side validation existed, you might as well just unlock for the device, without requiring any code input..

Comment: @JariKomppa The codes can be single use, with server side validation. If server side validation existed, you'd still have to know which device to unlock, the easiest way to do that would be unlocking the one requesting an unlock with a valid code.